How to trigger API, on Leave site ? popup
I'm using angular as front end and C# for backend for application, When I close tab Chrome showing "Leave site?" popup:

When I click the Leave button, I need to trigger an API, when I click cancel, api should not trigger
My code is:
@HostListener('window:unload', ['$event'])
  unloadHandler($event) {
    this.LogOutByTabClose($event);
  }

LogOutByTabClose($event) {
   
    const logoutData = {
      "UserId": UserService.UserId,
      "UserName": UserService.UserName,
      "DisplayName": UserService.DisplayName,
      "Apptype": UserService.Apptype,
      "Machinename": UserService.MachineName,
      "ConnectionString": null,
      "LogoutfromAll": false,
      "isUserUnlocked": ""
    };
    if (navigator.sendBeacon) {
      const logouturl = 'http://localhost:64359//api/Shared/LogoutUser';
      const headers = new Headers();
      headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      headers.append('x-token', UserService.AuthToken != null ? UserService.AuthToken : "Undefined");
      headers.append('x-session-userid', UserService.UserId + "^" + UserService.DisplayName);
      headers.append('x-session-token', UserService.CscToken != null ? UserService.CscToken : "Undefined");
      
      navigator.sendBeacon(logouturl, JSON.stringify(logoutData));
    } 
  }

I kept debug in navigator.sendBeacon and API in backend.
When I click the leave button, UI debug is hitting, but immediately tab is closed, backend debug is not hitting, and API is not triggered.
